# parse complex xml with php [maybe 2 foreach loops]?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

```
<Lineups date="2015-06-11">
<Game start_time="2015-06-11 09:10:00" number="901" revised="false">
<Team number="901" name="San Diego">
<Player name="Wil Myers" position="CF"/>
<Player name="Will Venable" position="LF"/>
<Player name="Matt Kemp" position="RF"/>
<Player name="Yonder Alonso" position="1B"/>
<Player name="Derek Norris" position="C"/>
<Player name="Cory Spangenberg" position="2B"/>
<Player name="Will Middlebrooks" position="3B"/>
<Player name="Alexi Amarista" position="SS"/>
<Player name="Andrew Cashner" position="P"/>
</Team>
</Game>
</Lineups>
```

I have this xml file and I want to parse it in php so I can display it on a website.

There're multiple games and each team has multiple players. Do I have to use a foreach loop within another foreach loop?

I want to display something like this:

> Game[0] start time
>   Name team[0] 
>   Player[0] 
>   Player[1] 
>   Player[2] 
>   ... 
>   Name team [1]
>
> Game[1]start time
>   Name team[0]
>   Player[0]
>   ...

Can someone more skilled get me started with how should I start my php code for parsing this xml file?

Comment: A reference question on parsing XML and HTML with PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow using simplexml

```
$str = '<Lineups date="2015-06-11">
<Game start_time="2015-06-11 09:10:00" number="901" revised="false">
<Team number="901" name="San Diego">
<Player name="Wil Myers" position="CF"/>
<Player name="Will Venable" position="LF"/>
<Player name="Matt Kemp" position="RF"/>
<Player name="Yonder Alonso" position="1B"/>
<Player name="Derek Norris" position="C"/>
<Player name="Cory Spangenberg" position="2B"/>
<Player name="Will Middlebrooks" position="3B"/>
<Player name="Alexi Amarista" position="SS"/>
<Player name="Andrew Cashner" position="P"/>
</Team>
</Game>
</Lineups>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

foreach ($xml->Game as $game) {
   echo "Game number " . $game['number'] . " start_time " . $game['start_time'] . "\n"; 
   foreach($game->Team as $team) {
     echo "  Team " . $team['name'] . " number " . $team['number'] . "\n";
     $players = array();
     foreach($team->Player as $player) $players[]  = $player['name'] . " ";  
     echo "    " . implode(", ", $players) . "\n"; 
   }
 }
```

result

```
Game number 901 start_time 2015-06-11 09:10:00
  Team San Diego number 901
    Wil Myers , Will Venable , Matt Kemp , Yonder Alonso , Derek Norris , Cory Spangenberg , Will Middlebrooks , Alexi Amarista , Andrew Cashner
```